# Can't export .mov with premiere pro cs5.5?

Tags: premiere, mpeg, quicktime

I'm trying to export a mpeg format sequence to .mov (I need it to be quicktime for a ceratin reason). When I choose the format, e.g. quicktime animation or quicktime H.264, It opens an 'encoding' window, and stays on 0% forever.

Exporting other formats works great. What could be the problem?

I'd be happy to include more information as soon as I know which info is relevant.

Comment: Which OS are you using? From your Q, it appears that you just want to convert a clip, has it been edited in any way? If not, that opens up non-Premiere possibilities.

Comment: Eventually I've exported it as mp4 and then converted to mov using SUPER converter which I recommend, but still would like to understand what went wrong. I'm using win 7. Video shot with 5d. Also, I found out that it IS possible to export .mov out of different sequence settings. Or maybe 5d is just too much for my 4 GB computer?

Comment: Are you using Adobe Encoder or are you exporting directly from Premiere Pro? Also, what settings are you using?

Comment: Install or reinstall the Quicktime player.
That's all.
:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your Quicktime install has been messed up, possibly by iTunes or something else installing Quicktime.  Try reinstalling Quicktime Player or the whole of Premiere if you can face it...

Comment: Installing Quicktime did it.